# Data Annotation Decimal ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core

Muy buen día, seré breve.

Podrían decirme el ***¿Por qué no se almacenan los decimales?***

Tengo en mi modelo

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public decimal Precio { get; set; }
```

En mi vista trate de usar step="0.01" para indicar que permito valores con decimales

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Precio" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="Precio" class="form-control" step="0.01"/>
     <span asp-validation-for="Precio" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

En mi método Edit tengo

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("PacienteID,FechaConsulta,Pieza,Precio,Observaciones")] Consulta consulta)
    {
        if (id != consulta.PacienteID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(consulta);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ConsultaExists(consulta.PacienteID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["PacienteID"] = new SelectList(_context.Paciente, "ID", "ID", consulta.PacienteID);
        return View(consulta);
    }
```

Al enviar mi formulario me aparece que se envía como entero sin decimales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método get Edit me llena el input con un valor con decimales en ceros y separados con una coma.

Muchas gracias por
su atención.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la data que tienes en la base de datos de ese registro, por favor?

Comment: Si inspeccionas el POST en el panel de Red de Chrome ¿se envía con o sin decimales?
Porque es posible que donde se esté perdiendo la información sea en el Model Binder (la parte de MVC que parsea los valores que le llegan para convertirlos y asignarlos a las variables que tienes declaradas en la firma de tu metodo)

Comment: @S. Bonet si, lo esta mandando como un 11, acaso hay problemas con el asp-for?